# How to load data in hive without using the variable name

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a list of 2000 variables in a weekly file. These 2000 variables are not fixed and i wanted to load this data into hive.

Currently,I  am getting the list of variables in the file using pearl and then manually loading the file by changing my hive code.

Is there any way i can automate the process?

Comment: Can you show the sample data? It is really hard to understand what you want to do and what problem(s) do you encounter.

Comment: The question is not clear. Please try elaborating more.